# MATLAB: extract numerical data from alphanumerical table and save as double

Tags: matlab

I created a list of names of data files, e.g. abc123.xml, abc456.xml, via

```
list = dir('folder/*.xml').
```

Matlab starts this out as a 10x1 struct with 5 fields, where the first one is the name. I extracted the needed data with struct2table, so I now got a 10x1 table. I only need the numerical value as 10x1 double. How can I get rid of the alphanumerical stuff and change the data type?

I tried regexp (Undefined function 'regexp' for input arguments of type 'table') and strfind (Conversion to double from table is not possible). Couldn't come up with anything else, as I'm very new to Matlab.

Comment: Is every file name guaranteed to have a number in it?

Comment: Yes. It's generated by some instrument, so the data output is consistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the `name` fields and place them in a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), use [`regexp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to capture the first string of digits it finds in each name, then use [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) to convert those to numeric values:

```
strs = regexp({list.name}, '(\d+)', 'once', 'tokens');
nums = str2double([strs{:}]);
```

Comment: Produces the error 'All cells must be strings'. I tried to apply the regexp to the struct matrix as well as the table, both with the same result. iscellstr(list.name) returns true at least for the transformed table, though.

Comment: too late to edit. I re-read your answer and found that using this regexp on the struct is useless. It should have worked on the 10x1 cell array (which returns iscellstr as true). Might work it out from here on, I hope.

Comment: I got it working by deleting the braces around {list.name}. Thank you very much. Now I'm just wondering if there's a more elegant solution...

Comment: @firefrog: If you have generated `list` as in your question (i.e. `list = dir('folder/*.xml')`), there should be no problems with the above code.